# How to implement RingtonePreference in PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Tags: android, android-fragments, deprecated, android-preferences, ringtone

I am creating an app using one `AppCompactActivity` and all other views are using Fragment. So I would like to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. But I am getting the following error when I create this.

```java
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class (not found)RingtonePreference
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(PreferenceInflater.java:300)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:358)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:360)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:167)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:117)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:115)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:366)
      at com.example.main.PreferenceFragmentSettings.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentSettings.java:18)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
      Didn't find class "android.support.v7.preference.RingtonePreference"
      on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.main-1/base.apk"],
      nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItem(PreferenceInflater.java:233)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.onCreateItem(PreferenceInflater.java:280)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(PreferenceInflater.java:289)
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:358) 
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:360) 
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:167) 
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:117) 
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:115) 
      at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:366) 
      at com.example.main.PreferenceFragmentSettings.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentSettings.java:18) 
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 

    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
          android.support.v7.preference.RingtonePreference
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 25 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
   boot class loader; no stack available
```

Please let me know is there any way to implement `RingtonePreference` in `PreferenceFragmentCompat`?

Comment: So did you find the solution? I'm having the same error, I must continue using the support library and there's no RingtonePreference in it...

Comment: The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom) mentions **picking a ringtone** as an example, too.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [*AndroidX Preference eXtended* library](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) which provides a `RingtonePreference`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not my solution, but I post it anyway, because it works.

> In you preferences XML resource, change RingtonePreference to
>   Preference. Then, in your implementation of PreferenceFragment, add:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {
>     if (preference.getKey().equals(KEY_RINGTONE_PREFERENCE)) {
>         Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
>         intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
>         intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
>         intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true);
>         intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
>
>         String existingValue = getRingtonePreferenceValue(); // TODO
>         if (existingValue != null) {
>             if (existingValue.length() == 0) {
>               // Select "Silent"
>                 intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
>             } else {
>                 intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Uri.parse(existingValue));
>             }
>         } else {
>           // No ringtone has been selected, set to the default
>             intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
>         }
>
>         startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ALERT_RINGTONE);
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference);
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ALERT_RINGTONE && data != null) {
>         Uri ringtone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
>         if (ringtone != null) {
>           setRingtonPreferenceValue(ringtone.toString()); // TODO
>         } else {
>           // "Silent" was selected
>           setRingtonPreferenceValue(""); // TODO
>         }
>     } else {
>         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     }
> }
> ```

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183255#c2).

Comment: It is better to provide link to the source as well.

Comment: Works fine. I'll add xml code in addition to this answer: in `settings.xml` your preference element may look something like this:         `<Preference
            android:key="settings_notification_ringtone"
            android:title="@string/settings_notification_ringtone" />` where "settings_notification_ringtone" is KEY_RINGTONE_PREFERENCE

Comment: but how to get the selected title value in order to add it to summary?

Comment: after implementing this, my settings screen is not loaded anymore. Because RingtonePreference is a child of PreferenceScreen, PreferenceCategory. Which means it's a separate screen. I just get a popup with selection of ringtones.

Answer (score 1):

For today ringtone preference does not exist in the support library. You need to use the framework's version or create your own.
I think it will appear soon

Answer (score 0):

If you need a **XAMARIN.Droid** version :

```
        public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ALERT_RINGTONE && data != null)
            {
                var ringtone = data.GetParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtonePickedUri);
                if (ringtone != null)
                {
                    SetRingtonePreferenceValue(ringtone.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    // "Silent" was selected
                    SetRingtonePreferenceValue("");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

        public override bool OnPreferenceTreeClick(Android.Support.V7.Preferences.Preference preference)
        {
            if (preference.Key == KEY_RINGTONE_PREFERENCE)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ActionRingtonePicker);

                intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneType, (int)RingtoneType.Notification);
                intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowDefault, true);
                intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowSilent, true);
                intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneDefaultUri, Android.Provider.Settings.System.DefaultRingtoneUri);

                string existingValue = GetRingtonePreferenceValue();
                if (existingValue != null)
                {
                    if (existingValue.Length == 0)
                    {
                        // Select "Silent"
                        intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneExistingUri, (Android.Net.Uri)null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneExistingUri, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(existingValue));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // No ringtone has been selected, set to the default
                    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneExistingUri, Android.Provider.Settings.System.DefaultRingtoneUri);
                }

                StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ALERT_RINGTONE);

                return true;
            }

            return base.OnPreferenceTreeClick(preference);

        }

        void SetRingtonePreferenceValue(string ringtone)
        {
            var editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.PutString(KEY_RINGTONE_PREFERENCE, ringtone);
            editor.Commit();
        }

        string GetRingtonePreferenceValue()
        {
            return prefs.GetString(KEY_RINGTONE_PREFERENCE, "content://settings/system/notification_sound");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Kotlin implementation based on [Dmitrijs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101249/356895) using `androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1`. I use the ringtone for alarms - therefore the different wording, `TYPE_ALARM` and `DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI`.

```
class AppSettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    // ...

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_TONE == requestCode && data != null) {
            val alarmToneUri = data.getParcelableExtra<Uri>(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI)
            onAlarmTonePicked(alarmToneUri)
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
    
    private fun onAlarmTonePicked(alarmToneUri: Uri?) {
        repository.updateAlarmToneUri(alarmToneUri)
    }
    
    override fun onPreferenceTreeClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
        return if (getString(R.string.preference_key_alarm_tone) == preference?.key) {
            onAlarmTonePreferenceClick()
        } else {
            super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference)
        }
    }
    
    private fun onAlarmTonePreferenceClick(): Boolean {
        val alarmToneUri = repository.readAlarmToneUri()
        val extras = bundleOf(
                RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE to RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM,
                RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT to true,
                RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT to true,
                RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI to Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI,
                RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI to alarmToneUri
        )
        val intent = Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER).apply { putExtras(extras) }
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_TONE)
        return true
    }

}
```