# Use a RingtonePreference in PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Tags: android, preference, preferencefragment

I am using PreferenceFragmentCompat for my settings activity, and would like to implement a RingtonePreference, which does not come with this type of Preference library.

The only other question on this topic does not have an answer on how to implement this ([How to implement RingtonePreference in PreferenceFragmentCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692522/how-to-implement-ringtonepreference-in-preferencefragmentcompat))

If anyone has does this and could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.  :)